# How to solve web socket I/O error: connection refused in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm using jmeter for gaming application which has both https and WSS connection. WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch is used to connect WebSocket.

It works perfectly in my machine, able to hit the server and received the response.

I try to run the same jmx file in other machine connection refused error occurred while connecting to web socket. Able to Https request successfully only WS failed.

Added all hosts in other machines but I can't able to find the Root cause of the error.

can anyone please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Using port 443 for WSS

Comment: Any answer regarding this issue??

Comment: Any help regarding this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the browser on different machines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I need to try using other browsers.

Comment: Curious whether websocket is not working just for Jmeter clients or even browser client

Comment: Websocket not working for jmeter client

Comment: Response message:WebSocket I/O error: Connection refused: connect error is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your configurations again, it is hard to believe that what you report is actually happening; i'll explain why. "connection refused" is an error on TCP level: it means the server actively refuses to accept the connection (it sends a TCP reset). At this point, HTTPS and WSS are not at play: these protocols run on top of TCP, so their handshake starts after the TCP connection is successfully set up. When receiving a TCP connect request, the server cannot know whether it is (will be) HTTPS or WSS. Therefore, your claim that HTTPS works, but WSS results in a "connection refused" error is weird and very unlikely. You should double check that you are using the correct hostname, port, etc, and that the HTTPS client is *really* connecting to the same server.

If this doesn't help, you should use WireShark or a similar tool to find out what is going on on (TCP) protocol level. Again, when the error is "connection refused" the problem is not in the WS or WSS or HTTP or HTTPS layer.

Hth
Peter

Comment: Thanks for the information.Will check with  WireShark and get back to you

Comment: @Amu did you get a fix around this? my application uses different port for every new instance. we use WSS serverName: `perf` Port: `8085` @Peter documentation says WSS works on 443 that is the reason for error. If you have got the answer for this please post it would be really helpful, thanks.